# How do I find the end of a file when putting lines in multiple variables (i.e. not using for line in f)

Tags: python, file, loops

I want to read 4 lines from a file and put each line in a separate variable. From what I can tell, I can't use:

```py
for file in f
```

since it only takes 1 line at a time, and I need to put 4 lines in 4 separate variables

my current "solution" looks like this:

```py
while f.readline != None:
            tempName = f.readline()
            print(tempName)
            tempColour = f.readline()
            tempAge = f.readline()
            tempWeight = f.readline()
            # this try is taking the varables and making an object
            try:
                tempSheep = Sheep(tempName, tempColour, int(tempAge), int(tempWeight))
            except:
                print("your file is in an improper format")
                break
            else:
                sheepList.append(tempSheep)
```

from what I can tell, the problem lies in the putting the variables in an object. The program runs through fine, then it runs through an extra time for some reason, in which case the variables are not properly filled with compatable data types, and the class throws an error.

Ultimately, I guess my question is: how do I make the loop exit correctly?

It is running beyond the end of the file, making variables equal to none, and then throwing an error when I make the object.

Sorry if this post is messy, this is my first post on stack overflow.

Comment: Do you want to read exactly 4 lines, once? Or 4 lines at a time in a loop?

Comment: `while f.readline != None:` will always be true.

Comment: `readline` is and always will be a function unless you redefine it. Maybe you meant to call() the function: `readline()`

Answer (score 0):

You can unpack the file object as an iterable into 4 variables, while reassigning the file variable with the rest of the lines for further unpacking:

```
with open('input_file') as f:
    lines = f
    while lines:
        try:
            name, colour, age, weight, *lines = lines
            sheepList.append(Sheep(name, colour, int(age), int(weight)))
        except Exception:
            print("your file is in an improper format")
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to what blhsing noted, you can write your code like this:

```
with open('some_file', 'r') as f:
  tempName = f.readline()
  tempColour = f.readline()
  tempAge = f.readline()
  tempWeight = f.readline()
  # if you want everything else from the file you can do this:
  # rest = f.read()
  # or if you want to continue parsing data line by line, you can do this:
  # for line in f:
  #   process_line(line)
```

You can then process the variables normally. If you are concerned about the file format being incorrect, you can wrap the with inside the try/except block